# Issues with masterpages/views/css

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

So my masterpage looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<link type="text/css" href="~/Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="~/Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
<body>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

My view looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/JQuery.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
   <div class="header">Welcome!</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And the CSS file looks like this:

```
div.header
{
     text-align: center;
}
```

However I'm not seeing center aligned text. What am I doing wrong? Also, will I need to make whatever changes to the JQuery .css files as well? Basically what I'm aiming for here is a single master page that I can use to hold all .css and javascript code so I don't have to reference it everywhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the generated output HTML of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to declare the all the `<script>` stuff in the header of the masterpage.